# Migrating EventEmitter to ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm getting an error that getToken is undefined when called as below and after transpiling with gulp-babel. Moving the constructor to bottom of class does not help either. Can anyone advise?

I think it has something to do with the util inheriting, which may be trying to take ES5 code and apply it to an area where ES6 does things very differently?

```
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');
class Report {

    constructor(private_key, service_email, debug) {
        this.private_key = private_key;
        this.service_email = service_email;
        this.debug = debug || false;

        events.EventEmitter.call(this);

        this.getToken( (err, token) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            return this.emit('ready');
        });
    }

    getToken(cb) {
        ...
    }
}

util.inherits(Report, events.EventEmitter);

module.exports = Report;
```

Comment: curious: does putting the constructor physically at the bottom help?

Comment: Can you show a complete code? (Verifiable..)

Comment: Works fine for me (`babel@5.5.8`).

Comment: @dandavis no, thanks for the idea though

Comment: Can you swap the `this.` prefixes? Just curious

Comment: @Amit I added some more code and my latest sense of what may be the problem

Comment: People should really read [ask]. Save the world a lot of time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>Judging by the call to `events.EventEmitter` in your constructor, you probably also using this:</s>

```
require('util').inherits(Report, events.EventEmitter);
```

This breaks the `Report` class (not sure why, but I can reproduce the problem).

Instead, use ES6-style inheritance:

```
class Report extends events.EventEmitter {

  constructor(private_key, service_email, debug) {
    super();
    ...
  } 

  getToken(cb) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `.inherits` replaces the `.prototype` of the `Reports` constructor, like `child_ctor.prototype = Object.create(parent_ctor.prototype);`

Comment: @squint yeah that seems to be right, iojs (with native class support) throws an TypeError because `ctor.prototype` is read-only (apparently something that Babel will allow at compile time, but it breaks at run time anyway).